# How to login to Google API in a server app and use Google Plus?

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-api-php-client, google-oauth

The initial task was as simple as this: get the latest post from a Google+ page.

It took 3 days now to find out that all examples on the Internet seem to be either outdated or wrong or not valid. Google developer docs also don't provide much help, complicating things more and more with every new confusing documentation page. So, guys, I'm giving up.

First I tried to implement OAuth 2.0 procedure which was documented in their docs (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer). As its title implies it is exactly about connecting from a server app. I followed it, and at first glance, it worked: I got the back call, successfully authenticated, fetched access token and stored it and made a simple call to fetch the posts.

```php
// Initialization

$this->googleClient = new Google_Client();
$this->googleClient->setAuthConfig(Json::decode($config->get('client_json')));
$this->googleClient->setAccessType('offline');
$this->googleClient->setIncludeGrantedScopes(TRUE);
$this->googleClient->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me');
$this->googleClient->setRedirectUri(Url::fromRoute('mymodule.gplus.callback')->setAbsolute()->toString());

// The callback

$client->authenticate($code);
$accessToken = $client->getAccessToken();
```

(The only thing which seemed silly here - is the scope. I had no idea what scope should I claim for if I need to just read a public post from a public page, so I just picked the first random entry which looked related.)

As I said I got the token and could fetch my posts:

```php
// Using Google_Service_Plus

$this->client()->setAccessToken($access_token);
$this->googleServicePlus = new Google_Service_Plus($this->client($reset));
$this->googleServicePlus->activities->listActivities($endpoint, 'public', ['maxResults' => 1]);
```

But after 1 hour it just stopped working claiming that the token is outdated or something and it needs to be refreshed. And here comes the showstopper: I found no way to refresh the token. `$response` from `authenticate()` doesn't return refresh token anymore (although it's been mentioned many times in other answers) so I don't even have a way to refresh it.

I tried digging in the library (from my `composer.json`: `"google/apiclient": "^2.0"`) and figured out that `authenticate()` method is actually deprecated there are few other methods which seem to play with tokens. I tried `\Google_Client::fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion()` which asked for some *Application Default Credentials*... which leads us to completely different topic and way of authentication described here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

So should I abandon everything which I did and now implement something new? How could I just do this simple task of fetching news?

Sorry for the long question.

Answer (score 1):

The process you are following is good. The problem you are having is refreshing the token. Although the official documentation states:

> If you use a Google API Client Library, the **client object** refreshes the access token as needed as long as you configure that object for offline access.

It does not explain how to do it using the PHP Client Library. This was a problem for me too so this is the approach I'm taking and hopefully it can help you.

```
// 1. Build the client object
$client = new Google_Client(); 
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/index.php');
$client->setAuthConfig("client_secret.json");
$client->addScope($scopes);
$client->setAccessType("offline");
```

I normally save the Access Token to the session, therefore before proceeding, I check if the access token is already saved to the session. If it is, then I proceed to check if the access token is already expired. If it is, then I proceed to refresh the access token, and then I proceed to make the API Call.

```
// 2. Check if the access token is already saved to session
if( isset($_SESSION["access_token"]) && ($_SESSION["access_token"]) ) {

    //set access token before checking if already expired
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION["access_token"]); 

    //check if access token is already expired and refresh if so
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) { 
        $refreshToken = $_COOKIE["refresh_token"]; //get refresh token
        $client->refreshToken($refreshToken); // refresh the access token
    }

    //get new access token and save it to session
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken(); 

    // set access token after checking if already expired
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION["access_token"]); 

    $plusService = new Google_Service_Plus($client);  

    $optParams = array(
        "maxResults" => 5,
        "pageToken" => null
    );

    $activitiesList = $plusService->activities->listActivities("+cnn", "public", $optParams);

    $activities = $activitiesList->getItems();

    foreach ($activities as $activity ) {
        print_r($activity);
        print "<br>**********************<br>";
    }


}
```

If the access token is not saved to the session, this means that the authentication and authorization has not taken place, so I proceed to authenticate the user.

```
// 3. Authenticate user since access token is not saved to session
else {

  if( !isset($_GET["code"]) ){ //get authorization code 

    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($authUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

  } else { //exchange authorization code for access token

    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']); //authenticate client

    //get access token and save it to session
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

    //save refresh token to a Cookie
    $refreshToken = $_SESSION["access_token"]["refresh_token"];
    setcookie("refresh_token", $refreshToken, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");

    $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/index.php';
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

  }

}
```

**Please note:** For demonstration purposes, I'm saving the refresh token to a cookie in this example; However, it is well known that you should not save this info to a cookie but instead to a secure database. Also, the `authenticate()` method is not deprecated, it's just an alias for the method `fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode()`. Another thing, the scope you are using is not *silly*, since you are fetching info from a public page, according to the documentation [**here**](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#plusv1) and **[here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities/list)**, I intuited that I should only allow access to **Know who you are on Google** `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me`.